# ZF3 Inject part of global config into a service factory

Tags: php, factory, zend-framework3

I have a service defined in `Module.php`, where I inject my `mail` config, defined in `config/autoload/global.php` this way:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
}

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => [
            'Mailer' => function($container) {
                return new MailService($this->getConfig()['mail']);
            },

        ]
    ];
}
```

But I want to do it the ZF3 way (wich I'm learning, so I defined my service in my `module.config.php` this way:

```
return [
    'services' => [
        'factories' => [
            Service\MailService::class => MailServiceFactory::class
        ]
    ],
```

And my `MailServiceFactory.php` is:

```
class MailServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        return new MailService();
    }
}
```

But how can I retreive my config defined in `global.php` and inject it in the factory, needed by my service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after some debug and `var_dump()`, I have it. I can access the config array thanks to `$container->get('configuration')`. So my factory is now:

```
class MailServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $config = $container->get('configuration');
        return new MailService($config['mail']);
    }
}
```